# how to get the index of every array on multidimensional array with unknown depth in php

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(16) "Daerah Pertanian" ["sub"]=> array(6) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(5) "Sawah" ["value"]=> string(3) "145" } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(18) "Sawah Pasang Surut" ["value"]=> string(3) "455" } [2]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(6) "Ladang" ["value"]=> string(3) "678" } [3]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(10) "Perkebunan" ["value"]=> string(3) "688" } [4]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(19) "Perkebunan Campuran" ["value"]=> string(3) "966" } [5]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(16) "Tanaman Campuran" ["value"]=> string(3) "565" } } } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(22) "Daerah Bukan Pertanian" ["sub"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(18) "Hutan Lahan Kering" ["sub"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(25) "Hutan Lahan Kering Primer" ["value"]=> string(3) "566" } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(27) "Hutan Lahan Kering Sekunder" ["value"]=> string(3) "255" } } } [1]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(17) "Hutan Lahan Basah" ["sub"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(24) "Hutan Lahan Basah Primer" } [1]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(26) "Hutan Lahan Basah Sekunder" } } } } } }
```

I have an array like I mention above, so I want to print out every "name" key including the index (number) of it's array parent,

for example when I print out "Tanaman Campuran" so all index parent is (0)(5) and when I print "Hutan Lahan Basah Sekunder" the index parent is (1)(1)(1)

how can I achieve it?

here is some recursive function that I've tried

```
$GLOBALS['all'] = '';
    function printout($arr){
        foreach ($arr as $ia=>$a){
            if(is_array($a)){
                foreach ($a as $ib=>$b){
                    if(is_array($b)){
                        printout($b);
                    }
                    else{
                        if ($ib == 'name') {
                            $GLOBALS['all'] .= $ia;
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td>' . $b . ' (' . $ia . ')</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                            $GLOBALS['all'] = '';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

*sorry for my bad explanation, I hope you guys can understand it

Comment: post you try first otherwise no one will help you out

Comment: I've edit my question, and adding my sample code, please checkout

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following function:

```
function search(array $array, $name)
{
  foreach ($array as $key => $entry) {
    if ($entry['name'] === $name) {
      return [$key];
    }
    if (isset($entry['sub']) && $found_keys = search($entry['sub'], $name)) {
      return array_merge([$key], $found_keys);
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

It returns:

- if the value was directly found, an array of one containing the associated index,
- if it wasn't but was found in any descendant item, an array merging its index with the indices of said descendant,
- `null` if it wasn't found in that part of the tree.

Note: if a given name is present several times, it will only find the first occurrence.

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/1hGr1**